# The `take` action seems not to trigger all tasks to run in spark

Tags: apache-spark

Recently I run a spark program and find that the take action seems not to trigger all tasks to run in spark.
When I use `take`, the result on spark UI is like this
[image]
While when I use `count`,
[image]

Note the difference between task numbers.
What I know is the action trigger lazy computations, but I can't find any related issues documented. I need some clarification, thanks.

Comment: take is executed on executors but count is executed on driver. so they are different in a sense that count counts all the records whereas take is executed in executor only taking specified number of records. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is normal. `take` iteratively evaluates partitions until it collects requested number of records. With [narrow dependencies](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-rdd-NarrowDependency.html) (`maps`, `flatMaps`, `filters`)  it can evaluate only a minimal number of partitions.

For example:

```
sc.range(0, 100, 1, 5).map(_ % 11).filter(_ >= 2).take(1)
```

requires only one partition to be evaluated

Only wide dependencies (operations which require shuffle like any `byKey` or sorting) require evaluating more partitions:

```
sc.range(0, 100, 1, 5).map(_ % 11).map((_, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _).take(1)
```

will trigger 6 tasks (5 for all upstream partitions and 1 for take).